# Are the souls in heaven conscious of their previous earthly existence?

Tags: heaven, souls

Is there any continuity between both stages of existence? Or does resurrection mean a complete new begin on a completely different level?

Comment: VERY closely related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14467/how-can-heaven-exist-if-we-know-that-people-in-hell-will-suffer

Comment: Kinda of depends if your body is resurrected physically or just your spirit.  Please define the context / denomination.

Comment: If you aren't resurrected physically, then you deny 1 Corinthians 15, the Nicene Creed, and about 2000 years of Christian history. Only Gnostics believe in a strictly spiritual resurrection, and the church pretty well decided that was heresy a long time ago.

Comment: @AffableGeek With that said, there is disagreement over whether our current bodies will be raised imperishable, or whether we will receive new bodies of some sort... and of what sort that might be. So, I still think Dan's request to specify a denomination and context is warranted.